# PostgreSQL and C++ - Compare dates

Tags: c++, postgresql, date, compare

I have a C++ function called `date()` which returns the current date as a string:

```
string date()
{
   time_t seconds = time (NULL);
   struct tm * timeinfo = localtime (&seconds);
   ostringstream oss;
   oss << (timeinfo->tm_year + 1900) 
       << "-" << (timeinfo->tm_mon + 1) 
       << "-" << timeinfo->tm_mday; 
   string data = oss.str();

   return data;
}
```

I need to compare the returned value of `date()` with a value stored in one of my tables. This is what I've tried so far:

```
if(strcmp(PQgetvalue(res,row,col),date()) != 0)
```

However, the compiler keeps throwing me the following error:

> **error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’**

Could anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: For conversion try to use c_str() function.

Comment: You'll save a lot of time and hassle if you use `libpqtypes` to take care of most of this sort of thing.

Comment: For now, I just needed a quick solution to implement in a project. Later, I'll look into it!

Comment: Wait a second... you do know about the `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` functions in PostgreSQL, right? (For example, try running the following DML statement: `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` on any of your databases.)

Answer (score 2):

1 - You can use string's c_str() method to get the access to the underlying C string:

```cpp
if(strcmp(PQgetvalue(res,row,col),date().c_str()) != 0)
```

2 - Even better, if you want to go "full C++", convert the output of `PQgetvalue` to string, and use the comparison operator:

```cpp
if(string(PQgetvalue(res,row,col)) == date())
```

Comment: Your 2nd point should be the first one. And you even can omit explicit char pointer's conversion to string.